# ERROR : Message: Call to a member function rekod() on null

Tags: php, codeigniter

I Keep getting this error and do not understand what is wrong.

An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Call to a member function rekod() on null

Filename: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mpklang\smk\application\controllers\Home.php

Line Number: 105

This is my controller:

```
public function Master_Fail()
    {
        $this->d['harta'] = $this->post_data->rekod();
        $this->load->view('menu/master_header_view',$this->d);
        $this->load->view('harta_baru/post_data',$this->d);
        $this->load->view('menu/master_footer_view');
    }
```

This is my model

```
public function rekod()
    {

        $query = $this->db->query("select (select count(1) jum from SMK.AKAUN_SEMASA_HARTA_BARU_SB where no_akaun is not null) harta_baru,(select count(1) jum from 
        SMK.AKAUN_SEMASA_SB where no_akaun is not null) semasa FROM dual");
        return $query->result_array();

         if($query->num_rows() > 0) 
         {
            return $query;
         }

    }
```

This is my view:

```
<?php 
                                                foreach ($harta as $row)
                                                { 
                                                  ?>

                                            <tbody>

                                                <tr>
                                                  <td>Rekod Semasa</td>
                                                  <td><?php echo $row['SEMASA']; ?> </td>
                                                  <td><?php echo $row['SEMASA']; ?> </td>
                                                  <td> </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                  <td>Rekod Baru</td>
                                                  <td><?php echo $row['HARTA_BARU'];?> </td>
                                                  <td><?php echo $row['HARTA_BARU']; }?></td>
                                                  <td> </td>
                                                </tr>
                                               </tbody>
```

Please help, thank you.

Comment: you should load model first before use in controller. either load in `autoload` or `constructor` of class or in specific `method`

Comment: its work..thank you...

Answer (score 1):

I think you have not loaded the Model `post_data`.
Load the model in your constructor as below. It will work.

```
public function __construct(){    
    $this->load->model('post_data');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should load model first before using `rekod()`

here are many ways as below

1. if you want to use only one method of that model, then you can load model in controller function as below

   `public function Master_Fail()
       {
           $this->load->model('post_data');
           $this->d['harta'] = $this->post_data->rekod();
           $this->load->view('menu/master_header_view',$this->d);
           $this->load->view('harta_baru/post_data',$this->d);
           $this->load->view('menu/master_footer_view');
       }`

2 . if you want to use in entire controller , then load in constructor of that controller as

```
public function __construct(){    
    $this->load->model('post_data');
}
```

3. if you want to use through application then put in the autoload.
 location is `config/autoload` file